# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Serving static files for react application: index.html and icons found, but js files not

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, static-files

I created an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web App and in a different folder created react application using create-react-app tool. I'm trying to connect these apps, but when I open the mapped endpoint I can see only index.html was downloaded, and js files are not found.
I mapped the specific path to SPA because in future i need one more SPA to be served.
ASP.NET Core startup:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(config =>
            {
                config.RootPath = "../clients/game-app/build";
            });

            // ...
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

            // ...
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.MapWhen(c => c.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/game"), client =>
            {
                client.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.SourcePath =  "../clients/game-app";
                    spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
                    {
                        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "../clients/game-app/build"))
                    };

                    if (_env.IsDevelopment())
                        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
                });
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

folders structure:

```
root
    - Project.sln
    - clients
        - game-app
            - build
            - files created by create-react-app
    - Project
        - ...
        - Startup.cs
        - wwwroot/game-app/build - copy of build from game-app folder
```

I swear it was working as it is now. I even did a commit to save everything, because I was struggling with this a lot. But now it stopped working. I suspect what I did wrong is I didn't shut down react dev server before commit.

Now it's not working:

[image: js-not-found]

What can be a root cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the thing is when I'm trying to use some mapped path to serve as react endpoint:

```
app.MapWhen(c => c.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/game"), client => {...});
```

This endpoint starts to serve as static file provider, so I can get index.html without issues. But index.html contains links to js files in this format:

```
/static/js/bundle.js 
which leads to 
localhost:4000/static/js/bundle.js
```

But the correct address is

```
localhost:4000/game/static/js/bundle.js
```

The workaround I found here : https://github.com/aspnet/Templating/issues/555

I added to package.json:

```
"homepage": "http://localhost:3000/game", // webpack dev server address
```

And it worked.